# reverse dns lookup with consul and dnsmasq

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, consul

I've setup consul (http://consul.io/) and dnsmasq so that I can have my own internal dns resolution.  I have tested with dig that consul supports reverse dns lookups:

```
$ dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 +noall +answer -x  11.0.16.69
69.16.0.11.in-addr.arpa. 0      IN      PTR     ip-11-0-16-69.node.dc1.consul.
```

However reverse dnslookups through dnsmasq fail. How do I configure dnsmasq to forward reverse lookup entries to consul?

I'm currently running consul with default configurations.  Each node has a consul agent started like so:

```
consul agent -data-dir=/tmp/consul -bind <ip> -node <short hostname>
```

Dnsmasq is running on each node with default configurations except for a single setting to forward dns requests to consul at port 8600.  There is a file at `/etc/dnsmasq.d/10-consul` that does this with content:

```
server=/consul/127.0.0.1#8600
```

Finally, I added an entry in `/etc/resolve.conf` to point to localhost so dnsmasq is used:

```
search us-gov-west-1.compute.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 11.0.0.2
```

I'm on AWS and it is vital that I can still leverage the dns service they provide in their environment as well as my own internal dns scheme.

Answer (score 4):

Add the line:

```
server=/16.0.11.in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#8600
```

To a file in `/etc/dnsmasq.d/some_name`

16.0.11 stands for any ip in the cidr `11.0.16/24`

So IP's in that range will get forwarded to the second section (consul agent dns running at port 8600).

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to access Consul's DNS through dnsmasq if ACLs are activated and the default policy is deny?